# Linux shell script hybrid graphic card

Tags: linux, shell

Im new to linux scripts. I need to make a script to run the following comands

```
sudo su
chown -R marko:marko /sys/kernel/debug;
chown marko:marko /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch;
exit;
echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch;
echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch;
echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch;
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch;
```

where marko is the username of the current logged user in the system.
Thanks

Comment: Copy it to a `file.sh`, add a `#!/bin/sh` at the top and `chmod +x` it. Then come with specific questions on the script.

Comment: additionally to fedorqui answer change marko:marko to $USER:$USER and the commands before 'exit' you should probably copy to a separate script file to be called by super user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better not to alter file permissions in `/sys` filesystem, you should write your script in a file, say `switcheroo.sh`, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

#If not running under sudo, force sudo
[ $UID -ne 0 ] && exec sudo "$0" "$@"

echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

and then execute it using `sudo ./switcheroo.sh`.

You must make the script executable with the command `chmod +x switcheroo.sh`.